# Search for one multibyte string in another multibyte string

Tags: php, multibyte

I use this code to search for one utf-8 string in another utf-8 string:

```
if (strlen(mb_stristr($string1, $string2)) > 0)
```

but it always returns 0! Does anyone know any better solution to this problem? Both strings may be some combination of unicode and non-unicode characteres!

Comment: I presume you just need to know whether or not the string occurs in the other string, or ?

Comment: Missing s in second variable name.

Comment: Yes, that right! I just want to check whether one string exists in another string or not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not using the substring, don't use `strstr` (or its derivitives).  All you care about is that the string exists, so use [`mb_stripos`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-stripos.php):

```
if (mb_stripos($string1, $string2) !== false) {
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use [mb_stripos](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-stripos.php)?

If you don't know the source encoding(s) you may need to use [mb_detect_encoding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) and subsequently [mb_convert_encoding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) to convert each of the strings into a common encoding, but this should be fairly trivial.

That said, you need to check for false in case string2 occurs at the start (i.e.: position zero) of string1.)

i.e.: Use...

```
if (mb_stripos($string1, $string2) !== false) {
    // $string2 was found within $string1
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (mb_stristr($string1, $string2) !== false) echo "found $string2 in $string2";
```

Note the type safe comparison operator `!==`.